# Finding duplicates in arrays

Tags: java, complexity, hash-map

I'm given two sorted arrays, `arr1` and `arr2`. They can either be of the same length or `arr2` will be longer than `arr1`. I implemented a method `findDuplicates` that returns an array of all numbers that are both in `arr1` and `arr2`. Note that the output array should be sorted in an ascending order.

I know there are better solutions than the one I came up with. What I'm trying to understand is the space complexity of the solution I came up with.

```
  static int[] findDuplicates(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
   // your code goes here
   HashMap<Integer, Integer> table = new HashMap<>();
   ArrayList<Integer> returnlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   int arr1Length = arr1.length;
   int arr2Length = arr2.length;

   // this is for the first array
   for(int i=0; i<arr1Length; i++){
      int n = arr1[i];
      table.put(n, 1);
   }

   for(int i=0; i<arr2Length; i++){
     int n = arr2[i];

     if(table.containsKey(n)){
       returnlist.add(n);
    }
  }
  int[] arr = new int[returnlist.size()];

  for(int i=0; i<=returnlist.size()-1; i++){
    arr[i] = returnlist.get(i);
  }
  return arr;
} // end of method
```

Since I created a temporary Hashtable and an ArrayList, and then another array to return the duplicates is my space complexity \$O(n^3)\$. I know its greater than \$O(n)\$. If someone can help me understand this better, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why \$\mathcal O(n^3)\$? Since you are creating a list _plus_ a map _plus_ an array, I only see \$\mathcal O(n+n+n)\$, which is equivalent to \$\mathcal O(n)\$.

Comment: @RolandIllig okay, that's what I was confused about. I thought it would be O(n^3) because I created three extra data structures to store the inputs in. It's not about the data structures but the size of the input. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is little bit tweaked algorithm, I am not holding any temporary variables to find duplicate (like HashMap or HashSet). Only temporary variable I am using is `List<Integer> duplicate` later I am converting it to int array, or else you can use `List<Integer>` but it depends upon your use case.

Below code only works if the arr1 and arr2 are sorted arrays, as per you problem statement.

```
static int[] findDuplicates(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    List<Integer> duplicate = new ArrayList<>();

    int[] largeArray;
    int[] smallArray;

    if(arr1.length == arr2.length) {
        largeArray = arr1;
        smallArray = arr2;
    } else {
        largeArray = arr1.length > arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;
        smallArray = arr1.length < arr2.length ? arr1 : arr2;
    }

    int largeArrayIndex = 0;

    for(int smallArrayIndex = 0; smallArrayIndex < smallArray.length; smallArrayIndex++) {
        for(; largeArrayIndex < largeArray.length; largeArrayIndex++) {
            if(largeArray[largeArrayIndex] == smallArray[smallArrayIndex]) {
                duplicate.add(largeArray[largeArrayIndex]);
                largeArrayIndex++;
                break; 
            } else if(smallArray[smallArrayIndex] < largeArray[largeArrayIndex]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(largeArrayIndex > largeArray.length) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return duplicate.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int[] findDuplicates(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
```

"Duplicates" is probably not the best name here. You would expect a duplicate to occur twice in the same collection of values or objects, not at least once in two collections. Maybe `findPairs` would be better, however still not perfect.

You might consider using an interface like `List` or even `Iterable` for the parameter types, to be able to support different types of collections instead of just arrays.

---

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> table = new HashMap<>();
```

Do you really need a `HashMap`? It seems like you always use `1` as value and actually just want the keys. Use `HashSet` in that case. Call it `uniqueValuesFirstArray` or similar, instead of table. Use a name that tells you what you use it for.

---

```
ArrayList<Integer> returnlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Call the list `result` or better `pairwiseOccuring` or `duplicates`, because that is what you are saving in it. The name should not imply what the code will be doing with it later, e. g. returning it.

---

```
int arr1Length = arr1.length;
int arr2Length = arr2.length;
```

This is obsolete. There is no reason to save these values, instead just access them directly.

---

```
// this is for the first array
for(int i=0; i<arr1Length; i++){
   int n = arr1[i];
   table.put(n, 1);
}
```

This comment is obsolete. The code tells you that it is for array1, even better if you improve your variable names and access the array's length directly, like `for (int i=0; i < array1.length; i++)`. Note the spaces that I added, to make it more readable.

Saving the value in a variable an then accessing it is obsolete. Just do `table.put(arr1[i], 1);`.

If you use `HashSet` instead of `HashMap`, you can replace the whole loop with `HashSet<Integer> uniqueValuesFirstArray = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array1));`

---

```
for (int i=0; i < arr2Length; i++) {
    int n = arr2[i];

    if (table.containsKey(n)) {
        returnlist.add(n);
    }
}
```

This is what the indentation and whitespaces in this part of your code should look like.

As above, you do not need the variable `n`. Just use the value from the array directly.

If you change `HashMap` to `HashSet`, replace `containsKey` with `contains`.

---

```
int[] arr = new int[returnlist.size()];

for(int i=0; i<=returnlist.size()-1; i++){
    arr[i] = returnlist.get(i);
}
```

This can be done much easier. Instead of the for-loop, just use `returnlist.toArray(arr);`. It is probably faster, and definitely shorter and more readable.